# Insert form value, which retrieved from database, again in to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a read-only text box which is retrieving max receipt no as it's value, from the database `sales` table.

```
<input name="txtReceiptNo" type="text" id="txtReceiptNo" size="10" value="<?php 
$receiptNo = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT max(sales_id)+1 FROM sales")); echo $receiptNo[0];?>" readonly />
```

When I try to send this to the database, it gives an error.

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'receipt_no' in 'field list'
```

(Yes, I know this is incorrect, but how can I correct this?)

**SQL Query:**

```
INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,receipt_no,qty,unit_price,discount,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 
SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, receipt_no='$receipt_no',ST.qty, ST.unit_price, ST.discount, ST.amount, U.id, P.purchase_id 
FROM customers C, items I, stock S, sales_temp ST, users U, purchase_items P
WHERE ST.staff='$user' AND 
C.customer_name='$customer' AND 
I.item_name=ST.item_name AND 
S.stock_code=ST.stock_code AND 
ST.purchase_id=P.purchase_id
```

### Edited Code:

```
INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,receipt_no,qty,unit_price,discount,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 
SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, receipt_no='$receiptNo',ST.qty, ST.unit_price, ST.discount, ST.amount, U.id, P.purchase_id 
FROM customers C, items I, stock S, sales_temp ST, users U, purchase_items P
WHERE ST.staff='$user' AND 
C.customer_name='$customer' AND 
I.item_name=ST.item_name AND 
S.stock_code=ST.stock_code AND 
ST.purchase_id=P.purchase_id
```

Comment: `$receiptNo` != `$receipt_no`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Darn it, you are fast

Comment: @Xorifelse Dyslexia has its advantages.

Comment: and error reporting would have thrown an undefined variable notice (first)..

Comment: *"(Yes, I know this is incorrect, but how can I correct this?)"* - A: Use the right variable (to start with).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I hope he mean this isnt the right way to do it because doesnt handle concurrency?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please apply it to my query.

Comment: `receipt_no='$receiptNo'` try that then see what that says. Then recheck for errors with `mysqli_error($connection)` to the query and look at your HTML source.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza TBH, a bit hard to say. So far, they're using the wrong variable.

Comment: @EKBG don't take this the wrong way, but I have to stop staring at the question till we see more activity. you can ping anyone of us if you have more to share.

Comment: I tried correcting `receipt_no='$receiptNo'`, now it says `#1054 - Unknown column 'receipt_no' in 'field list'`

Comment: You are giving Aliases to all the columns except reciept_no ? what table is reciept_no in ? give it an alias and try. ex: S.receipt_no='$receiptNo'

Comment: @Asim Yes, that's the issue. I am getting the previously inserted max receipt no from the same `sales` table, which I am inserting the data.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited the code, please see my previous comments.

Comment: @EKBG Does the `receipt_no` column exist in the `customers` table? What happens when you run it from inside phpmyadmin; does it work? If this is a JOIN-related issue, TBH I am not very good at those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it's only in `sales` table. When I run the above edited code inside phpmyadmin, it says, `#1054 - Unknown column 'receipt_no' in 'field list' `

Comment: well there you go @EKBG create it or don't use it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But, I have already put it, right?

Comment: you can't SELECT what doesn't exist. @EKBG

Comment: @Fred-ii- INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,**receipt_no**,qty,unit_price,discount,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 

This is what you are saying right?

Comment: Look at what you're doing here and very carefully.... `SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, receipt_no='$receipt_no'..... FROM customers`. The `receipt_no='$receipt_no'` is set inside that `SELECT FROM customers` declaration. @EKBG

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is not getting the value from `customers` table. `customers` table is for `INNER JOIN` purpose. As the `receipt_no` has to get from it's own `sales` table, I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the above issue.

Edited code is below:

```
INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,receipt_no,qty,unit_price,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 
SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, $receipt_no, ST.qty, ST.unit_price, ST.amount, U.id, P.purchase_id 
FROM customers C, items I, stock S, sales_temp ST, users U, purchase_items P 
WHERE ST.staff='$user' 
AND C.customer_name='$customer' 
AND I.item_name=ST.item_name 
AND S.stock_code=ST.stock_code 
AND ST.purchase_id=P.purchase_id
```